# How can i uninstall another program(exe) in wix installer?

Tags: wix

I have an old setup(exe), which i have been created through installshield. I want to upgrade my old app to new one or else uninstall old app in WIX Toolset. If any one have some idea please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. It might be an InstallShield setup that created an MSI file to be installed. If so you need to find its UpgradeCode and use Upgrade elements in your WiX, or use the same UpgradeCode as that old product and do a Major Upgrade.
2. If it's not MSI-based, it's a mess. A technique I've seen used is to locate the UninstallString for that product in the registry. You can read that out into a property with a RegistrySearch. What you do with it depends on what kind of uninstall you want. Once you have the uninstall string command there are a few things you need to worry about:

   a. If you run that uninstall string command as an immediate custom action it's likely to fail because immediate custom actions are not elevated.

   b. If you want it to be silent you'll have to inspect the uninstall command string programmatically and add the silent switch, and that will depend on whatever that version of InstallShield uses. There may also be a  "show uninstall progress" choice.

   c. If you run the uninstall silently as a deferred custom action it will be elevated if impersonation=no, but if it fails silently and your install proceeds anyway then there will be the old and new versions installed.

   d. If your install fails after you've uninstalled the older product the user will be left with neither product installed.

In other words there are no good options in case 2 because the chances of failure are high. In most cases the safe answer is to detect the older product and ask the user to manually uninstall it. Once you're in MSI-mode you can use the MajorUpgrade element to upgrade seamlessly.

Comment: I have gone through your 1st possibilities, now it works fine. Thank you so much for this suggestion, Actually i am new on Stackowerflow so i cant vote for you. I wish i could be able to do vote for you.

Comment: For non-MSI, "the safe answer is to detect the older product and ask the user to manually uninstall it" seems like a cop-out but is really quite reasonable.